# display pdf in browser using php

Tags: php, pdf

hi so im trying to display a pdf file in the browser using php so i used this code

```
<?php
    $filename = "uploads/docs/Preamble and National Territory.pdf";
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
?>
```

i juat hardcoded the pdf file name but will change it later my problem is it does not load the pdf file in my browser here is what it says

[image]

any idea how to improve my code? or what im doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: first check the file path

Comment: (a screenshot displaying that could have been a lot smaller.)

Comment: try wrapping it in if (file_exists($file)) {

Comment: hi it seems that the path is the problem. anyways when viewing pdf tht is not colored it does not show any ideas?